# Add minimum and maximum values on react-native-chart-kit-example

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-chart-kit

I am using this https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit, I want on the yAxis to have some stable minimum and maximum values, start from 1 and end on 4 even when there are not values for this range.
I have this

[image]

But what I need is this

[image]